# Using Guice 3 with JAX-WS in Java 6 outside web container

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jax-ws, guice

We have a situation where we use JSR-330 based injections to configure our stand-alone Java 6 applications, which works very well for getting configuration parameters across all the layers.

We have also used JAX-WS web services for quite a while by using first stand-alone Metro distribution with Java 5 inside a web container, but with Java 6 we just use the Endpoint class to get a smaller footprint.

So now I have a situation where I have

- A stand-alone Java 6 application - no servlet container (Jetty, Tomcat)
- A Guice 3 Injector set up as I like it.
- An `Endpoint` handling my `@javax.jws.WebService` annotated class which expose my methods as web services.

I would like the web service methods to either have their @Inject fields handled transparently, or to get access to the injector.  I *can* grab it as a static field from the main method, but I'd like a cleaner solution.

Any suggestions?

(I understand from [JAX-WS and Guice 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061626/jax-ws-and-guice-3) that the http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/guice/ module does not work with Guice 3, and the workaround suggested is Tomcat specific)

Would JSR-250 `@Resource` annotations be useful here?

Comment: It turned out that I can get by for now by injecting a provider in the implementation object as I do not need deeply nested injection.  Bounty awarded to answer making me realize this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that I've understood every bit of the question. It looks to too easy for +500 bounty. Please post some code if that's not what you're searching for.

Anyway, a simple solution which creates a web service with dependency injection:

```
final Module module = new HelloModule();
final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
final HelloService helloService = injector.getInstance(HelloService.class);

Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/helloService", helloService);
```

Below a more sophisticated solution with classpath scanning ([Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)) based on Marcus Eriksson's code from [JAX-WS Guice integration](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/guice/). It publishes all classes which is annotated with `@GuiceManaged` as a webservice with `Endpoint.publish()`.

```
private void initGuicedWebservices(final String packageNamePrefix) 
        throws Exception {
    final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageNamePrefix);
    final Set<Class<?>> guiceManaged = 
        reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(GuiceManaged.class);
    for (final Class<?> clazz : guiceManaged) {
        doGuice(clazz);
    }
}

private void doGuice(final Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
    final GuiceManaged guiceManagedAnnotation = 
        clazz.getAnnotation(GuiceManaged.class);

    final Injector injector = createInjector(guiceManagedAnnotation);

    final Object serviceObject = clazz.newInstance();
    injector.injectMembers(serviceObject);

    final String address = guiceManagedAnnotation.address();

    Endpoint.publish(address, serviceObject);
}

private Injector createInjector(final GuiceManaged guiceManagedAnnotation) 
        throws Exception {
    final Class<? extends Module>[] moduleClasses = 
        guiceManagedAnnotation.module();

    final List<Module> moduleInstances = new ArrayList<Module>();
    for (final Class<? extends Module> moduleClass : moduleClasses) {
        moduleInstances.add(moduleClass.newInstance());
    }

    return Guice.createInjector(moduleInstances);
}
```

The `GuiceManaged` annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Documented
public @interface GuiceManaged {
    public Class<? extends Module>[] module();
    public String address();
}
```

And the `HelloServiceImpl` snippet:

```
@GuiceManaged(module = HelloModule.class, 
    address = "http://localhost:8080/helloService")
@WebService
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {

    @Inject // bound in HelloModule
    public GreetingsService greetingsService;

    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(final String name) {
        return greetingsService.sayHello(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: After a bit of pondering upon your answer, I realized that the Endpoint mechanism does not do any new's, but just call the @WebMethod annotated method.  This mean that I can get by for now just by having providers injected in the instance.  As always, some questions are only hard until you know how to do it.

Comment: Also I frequently use the 500 point bounty to attract attention to a question.  If others find the question simple and the answer trivial, that is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `AbstractMultiInstanceResolver` extension point.

create the annotation `GuiceManaged`;

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Documented
@WebServiceFeatureAnnotation(id=GuiceManagedFeature.ID, bean=GuiceManagedFeature.class)
@InstanceResolverAnnotation(GuiceManagedInstanceResolver.class)
public @interface GuiceManaged {
}
```

implement the `GuiceManagedFeature` which is `WebServiceFeature` :

```
public class GuiceManagedFeature extends WebServiceFeature {
    public static final String ID="FEATURE_GuiceManaged";

    @FeatureConstructor
    public GuiceManagedFeature()
    {
        this.enabled=true;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

Implement `InstanceResolver` by Extending `AbstractMultiInstanceResolver`

```
public class GuiceManagedInstanceResolver extends AbstractMultiInstanceResolver {
    private T instance=null;
    public GuiceManagedInstanceResolver(@NotNull Class clazz)
    {
        super(clazz);
    }
    public T resolve(@NotNull Packet request) {
        if(instance==null)
        {
            instance=create();
            Injector injector= Guice.createInjector(new WebServiceModule());
            injector.injectMembers(instance);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now Annotate your Service with `@GuiceManaged` & use `@Inject` for method level DI on your business method.

Comment: Were you inspired by http://developian.blogspot.com/2008/11/google-guice-and-jax-ws.html ?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, Long back, we had such problem like your one and we tried to use that blog as reference, then we found Guice-Fruit with Guice 2.x.

Comment: Does this mean you now use Guice-Fruit and have to stay with Guice 2?