# Injecting Guice into JAX-WS POJO

Tags: jboss, jax-ws, guice

I am using JBoss 7.1 and Java 1.6.

I would like to integrate a [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) service with by JAX-WS endpoint.  Using the interceptor pattern described by Gunnar.Morling I am able to properly instantiate the Guice modules when using a stateless bean as a webservice. However i am not able to do the same with a simple POJO annotated webservice. Is this possible has anyone found a workaround. Below is a summary of my efforts so far.

```
@UsesGuice @Interceptor
public class GuiceInterceptor {

  @Inject
  private GuiceInjectorHolderBean injectorHolder;

  @AroundInvoke
  public Object aroundAdvice(final InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
    if (ctx.getTarget().getClass().isAnnotationPresent(UsesGuice.class)) {
        final Injector injector = injectorHolder.getInjector();
        injector.injectMembers(ctx.getTarget());
    }
    return ctx.proceed();
  }
}
```

The GuiceInjectorHolderBean is the a sinlgeton bean responsible for triggering the guice wiring. The annotation class required follows

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE) 
@InterceptorBinding 
public @interface UsesGuice {}
```

the JAX-WS POJO class

```
@UsesGuice
@WebService(serviceName = "EchoServiceService", portName = "EchoServicePort", ame = "EchoServiceImpl", targetNamespace = "lala")
public class EchoServiceImpl implements EchoService
{
  @Inject
  MyGuiceInjection injection;

  @Override
  @WebMethod
  public String sayHello(final String msg)
  {
    return "Hello " + injection.call(msg);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance
Dimitri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Current Approach**

In your code, `javax.interceptor` annotations `@Interceptor`, `@InterceptorBinding` and `@AroundInvoke` are supported by CDI and EJB standards and not by Guice.  Guice uses proprietary [AOP](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP) interception via `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor` interface and calling the method `AbstractModule.bindInterceptor`.

So you're trying to bootstrap Guice injection on your endpoint by:

1. using a *non-Guice interceptor* on the endpoint's method
2. within the `@AroundInvoke` method, programmatically invoking the Guice `Injector`, with injection target being the intercepted endpoint

That begs the Q, what to use for 1?

**'Bootrap' Interception Mechanism for Your Current Approach**

Obviously, an EJB interceptor works, as you've stated.

Other than an EJB or Guice AOP interceptor... an obvious alternative would be the standard, a CDI interceptor.

But that would make it all rather circular and heavy-weight... Why use CDI just to boostrap, so that you can configure and execute to your desired DI competitor: Guice?

**Suggested Alternative Solution - JAX-WS Support for Manual Endpoint Instance Initialisation**

If you want POJO web services, maybe consider back-tracking a bit, instead of interceptor-driven Guice initialisation, maybe this could be what you need:

```
 javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(String address, Object implementor)
```

[Endpoint.publish javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#publish%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Initialise Guice in the standard way, use `injector.getInstance()` to construct your endpoint instance, and then use `Endpoint.publish` to set the endpoint instance against the port.  The following gives a good example:

[Using Guice 3 with JAX-WS in Java 6 outside web container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687204/using-guice-3-with-jax-ws-in-java-6-outside-web-container)